# Consul acl create getting permission denied despite setting CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN

Tags: javascript, node.js, consul

I use [npm consul](https://www.npmjs.com/package/consul) client.

I have set `CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN` as environment variable, and tried to create token using `consul.acl.create` but I get `Permission denied`

```
//code
const express = require("express");
const consul = require("consul")();

console.log('Bootstrap token is ', process.env.CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN);

consul.acl.create((err, result) => {
  if(err) {
    console.error('found error', err);
}});
```

Output is :

```
Bootstrap token is  AccessorID:       9d0d8271-b8aa-6b03-c4f5-dce653853653
consul_1  | SecretID:         f4a6ffc0-2a16-517e-d1c5-645eaaeb5f7a
consul_1  | Description:      Bootstrap Token (Global Management)
consul_1  | Local:            false
consul_1  | Create Time:      2021-03-19 20:19:16.9918012 +0000 UTC
consul_1  | Policies:
consul_1  |    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001 - global-management
2021-03-19T20:19:17.139Z [ERROR] agent.http: Request error: method=PUT url=/v1/acl/create from=127.0.0.1:43776 error="Permission denied"
consul_1  |     2021-03-19T20:19:17.139Z [DEBUG] agent.http: Request finished: method=PUT url=/v1/acl/create from=127.0.0.1:43776 latency=170.7µs
consul_1  | found error Error: Permission denied
consul_1  |     at create (/app/node_modules/papi/lib/errors.js:14:5)
consul_1  |     at Object.response [as Response] (/app/node_modules/papi/lib/errors.js:38:15)
consul_1  |     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/papi/lib/client.js:592:26)
consul_1  |     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:326:22)
consul_1  |     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)
consul_1  |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
consul_1  |   isPapi: true,
consul_1  |   isResponse: true,
consul_1  |   statusCode: 403
consul_1  | }
```

Config.json :

```
{
  "acl": {
    "enabled": true,
    "default_policy": "deny",       
    "enable_token_persistence": true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Consul client package will not automatically use the Consul token from the `CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN` environment variable. You must explicitly define a token to use either when initializing the Consul client, or for each request.

For example:

```js
import consul from 'consul';

// Read Consul token from environment variable
const bootstrapToken = process.env.CONSUL_HTTP_TOKEN;

// Initialize the Consul client
// Set a token to be used by default for every request
const defaultClientOptions = {
    defaults: {
        token: bootstrapToken
    }
}
const consulClient = new consul(defaultClientOptions);

// Query KV store for key 'test'
let kvQueryOptions = { key: 'test' }
consulClient.kv.get(kvQueryOptions, function (err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (!result) {
        console.log(`Key '${kvQueryOptions.key}' does not exist.`)
        return;
    }

    result.forEach(item => {
        console.log(item);
    });
});

// Query for key 'test2'
// Override the default token with a different token for this request
kvQueryOptions = {
    key: 'test2',
    token: 'C601F13E-AF45-4674-B6AB-BA50299DA0A4'
}

consulClient.kv.get(kvQueryOptions, function (err, result) { 
    if (err) throw err;

    if (!result) {
        console.log(`Key '${kvQueryOptions.key}' does not exist.`)
        return;
    }

    result.forEach(item => {
        console.log(item);
    });
});
```